# Restful Rails "perspectives"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I want to render a page that isn't necessarily tied to a model. Up until now I have been creating a controller titled, "Pages", and a route for each page:

```
map.home :controller => "pages", :action => "home"
```

This isn't restful and it is tedious. Surely there is a better way to handle "perspectives" such as this?

Note: I avoid the term "view" in order to distinguish between Rails views and what I wish to accomplish.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle this. [Josh Susser wrote a post](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/4/2/simple-pages) about it, and there is [a Railscast on a similar topic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages).

In short, there isn't a great way to handle it, but there is some room for improvements over the way you're doing it now.

HTH

Comment: Tim, this is fantastic. I really like Josh's solution. Thank you.